# How to get value from LiveData synchronously?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-architecture-components

For `LiveData`, is there something similar to `blockingNext` or `blockingSingle` in RxJava's Observable to get the value synchronously? if not, how can i achieve the same behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `getValue()` to return the current value, if there is one. However, there is no "block until there is a value" option. Mostly, that is because `LiveData` is meant to be consumed on the main application thread, where indefinitely-blocking calls are to be avoided.

If you need "block until there is a value", use RxJava and ensure that you are observing on a background thread.

Comment: so what is best way to test livedata ? i found this but i expect some simple way https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/test-common/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataTestUtil.kt

Comment: @Xan: I have used [this library](https://github.com/jraska/livedata-testing) with success.

Comment: to be used on both test and androidTest ?

Comment: @Xan: I used it with a unit test; I believe that it will work with instrumented tests as well.

Answer (score 1):

With Kotlin coroutines

```
callbackFlow {
    val observer = Observer<Unit> {
        trySend(Unit)
    }
    MutableLiveData<Unit>().also {
        it.observeForever(observer)
        awaitClose {
            it.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}.buffer(Channel.Factory.CONFLATED)
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.Main.immediate)
// e.g. single()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Future](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future) to synchronize your data like this:

```
 LiveData<List<DataModel>> getAllDatasForMonth(final String monthTitle) {
    Future<LiveData<List<DataModel>>> future = DatabaseHelper.databaseExecutor
            .submit(new Callable<LiveData<List<DataModel>>>() {
        @Override

        public LiveData<List<DataModel>> call() throws Exception {
            mAllDatasForMonth = mDataDao.getDatasForMonth(monthTitle);
            return mAllDatasForMonth;
        }
    });
    try {
        //with get it will be wait for result. Also you can specify a time of waiting.
        future.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException ex){
        Log.e("ExecExep", ex.toString());
    } catch (InterruptedException ei) {
        Log.e("InterExec", ei.toString());
    }
    return mAllDatasForMonth;
}
```