# kotlin Data Store

Tags: android, kotlin, datastore

```
var value: String = ""
    fun getValue(key: String, lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner): String {
        val data = dataStore.data.map { pre ->
            pre[preferencesKey<String>(key)]
        }
        data.asLiveData().observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer {
            value = it ?: "noData"
            Log.i("MONO", "A | $value")
        })
        return value
    }
```

**return log data is true
but in
return value data is null**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Android, but a quick Google indicates that the [`LiveData.observe()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20androidx.lifecycle.Observer)) method adds an observer.

This is clearly using the standard [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) that you find in many languages and frameworks.  The observer is informed (i.e. called) at the relevant time(s).

Note that the observer might *not* be called immediately.  In this case, it's clearly not: the `observe()` call returns after adding the observer, while your `value` is still `null`; and your `getValue()` method returns that null.  At some *later* point, the observer may be called and set `value`, but by then nothing cares about it.

I don't know LiveData well enough to advise on what to do, but I notice it has a [`getValue()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#getvalue) method that might do what you want, if the value is available immediately.

If not, you'll have to block until the observer is called.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069857/how-to-get-value-from-livedata-synchronously) would seem to indicate one way of doing that.  (The answer is in Java, but you can probably get the idea from that.)